# Undefined derivatives

Tags: calculus

If a given derivative  is undefined, will all following derivatives necessarily be undefined as well? For example, if the nth derivative is undefined, will the (n+1)th, (n+2)th, etc. derivatives all be undefined also? Or is it case by case and there is no general principle?

Comment: For the $n+1$th derivative to be defined, the $n$th derivative must **not only be defined, it must also be differentiable**. Of course, here your $n$th derivative is not even defined, so there is no question about the next derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: if a derivative does not exist at a point, then you can't differentiate it again since there's no function there!

The definition of a derivative is:

$$\frac{d}{{dx}}f\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + \Delta x } \right) - \color{red}{f\left( x \right)}}}{\Delta  x}$$

If $f$ is the derivative of some other function and it is undefined at $x=c$, then $f'(c)$ cannot exist because when you try to substitute everything in, the red part will not exist.